# convert curl PUT to ruby net:http

Tags: ruby, rest, https, net-http

I've searched all over the interwebs and read through https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.2/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html

I'm still unable to get the right syntax to convert the following curl command to ruby.  I'll spare you all the different ways I've tried.  Can someone please give me an example of what this should look like in Ruby?

```
curl -k -s -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X PUT --data '{"name": "anonymous", "password": "obfuscated"}' https://some.domain/repository/npm/-/user/org.couchdb.user:anonymous
```

All the examples I see are with POST not PUT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converted via Postman.

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'

url = URI("https://some.domain/repository/npm/-/user/org.couchdb.user:anonymous")

http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)

request = Net::HTTP::Put.new(url)
request["Accept"] = 'application/json'
request["Content-Type"] = 'application/json'
request["Cache-Control"] = 'no-cache'
request["Postman-Token"] = '9e3622cd-fda5-458d-2521-325849546ef7'
request.body = "{\"name\": \"anonymous\", \"password\": \"obfuscated\"}"

response = http.request(request)
puts response.read_body
```

Comment: thank you.  I had to also set http.use_ssl = true.  Bonus points for stearing me to Postman!